# SQL Server Management Studio Replacement

Tags: sql-server, macos, ssms

Can anyone suggest a non java replacement for SQL Server Management Studio for OSX?
I currently use Parallels in Crystal mode and run SSMS, but it seems like there should be something better.

Comment: out of curiosity why non java requirement ? without JDBC it is kinda difficult to connect to SQL Server from other OS. I deleted my reply that recommended razor sql btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I had to come back and add to this.  Navicat has a FREE solution for MySQL and MS SQL server.  They are both available (for free) in the mac app store.

App store links:

[Navicat for SQL Server](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/navicat-for-sql-server-lite/id412149217?mt=12)

[Navicat for MySQL](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/navicat-for-mysql-lite/id412581753?mt=12)

You may notice that they are both listed as "Lite".  Apparently the full version includes a Visual Query builder, data transfer, data synch, and backup and batch job scheduling.  For my personal needs, the Lite version has done everything I need, when I need to do the "heavy lifting" I just remote into a machine with Management Studio on it.

Answer (score 0):

i've heard good things about [Aqua Data Studio](http://www.aquafold.com/). Works on Win, OSX, Linux and Solaris.

Comment: +1, I know a mac weenie that uses this!  FYI, this person is a weenie regardless of the OS they use, and not because of it. ;-) I do think it uses java though

Comment: LOL!  I actually do a lot of development on both platforms, and was looking for a tool so that I didn't have to constantly switch to a VM when working on mac/iPhone projects.  Thanks for the recommendation, I'll give Aqua a try.

Answer (score 0):

aquafold doesn't work with sql dbms and navicat is NOT free.

Comment: Navicat did have a free version in the MAS, but it is no longer there.

Comment: Navicat crashes all the time, can hang for up to 30 seconds as soon as you type an alias because of the autocomplete, and doesn't let you edit your own sql files (lets you open them, but only lets you save to some weird internal location). In other words Navicat is a joke compared to SSMS. Keep using SSMS.

Comment: I didn't experience any of the problems you mentioned with the free version of Navicat.  I do agree that SSMS is the best experience, but it is not an option for users on platforms other then Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You may like [SQLPro for MSSQL](http://macsqlclient.com) ([App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/sql-client-database-management/id828466809?mt=12)).

Note: I'm the developer of this app, and I specifically developed it so that I could get away from leaving a virtual machine running 24/7.

There is a seven day trial available [via the website](http://macsqlclient.com), so if you are interested, you can always give it a try and see if it suits your needs.

Comment: Looks pretty good from the screen shots, I'll have to check it out!

Comment: @Mongo awesome! Let me know if you have any issues or questions. The latest version has a support button on the connection screen which can either take you to my support forum, or allows you to email me directly :)